# Read and write to the same file

Tags: php, file

Im trying to read and write to/from the same file, is this possible?

Here is what I am getting negative results with:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("filename.csv", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    fwrite($file,$line);
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Generally you open files with mode "r+" to read/write

Comment: You declared the file as read only initially.  Mark it as r+

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're opening the file in read-only mode.  If you want to write to the file as well, do
`fopen("filename.csv", "r+")`

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to open the file with more 'r+' instead of just 'r'.  See the documentation for fopen:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 5):

You opened the file in "read only" mode. See the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

```
$file = fopen("filename.csv", "r+") or exit("Unable to open file!");
```